# How can I add content above the app bar while using bottom content in the app bar?

Tags: flutter

To add content above the app bar I wrapped the regular app bar in a column and that column in a preferred size widget to use it in the scaffold as the app bar.
So far that works, however when I add a bottom content to the regular app bar it fails to build.

The failing scaffold looks something like this:

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + 50 + 50),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Text("top"),
              ),
              AppBar(
                title: Text(widget.title),
                bottom: const PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Text("bottom"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
```

This is the exception that was thrown:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#d89b4 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AppBar AppBar:file:///Users/carconsis/Documents/app_bar_test/lib/main.dart:99:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1979:12)
#3      RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:237:39)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#5      RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:437:14)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#12     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#18     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#19     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#20     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#22     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
#23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#24     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#25     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:948:22)
#26     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#27     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#28     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1757:7)
#29     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#30     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:504:19)
#31     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:892:13)
#32     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#33     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#34     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#35     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
#39     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#40     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#41     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPadding#9e6b1 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(392.7, 108.7)
...  padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 52.7, 0.0, 0.0)
...  textDirection: ltr
RenderObject: RenderPadding#9e6b1 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(392.7, 108.7)
  padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 52.7, 0.0, 0.0)
  textDirection: ltr
...  child: RenderFlex#d89b4 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 52.7) (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: vertical
...    mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#8462b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.loose
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=56.0)
...      child: RenderClipRect#e5322 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        child: RenderCustomSingleChildLayoutBox#b0c7f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...    child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#8f9db NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=50.0)
...      child: RenderParagraph#19aed NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: start
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: clip
...        locale: en_US
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          debugLabel: (englishLike bodyMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView bodyMedium)
...          inherit: false
...          color: Color(0xdd000000)
...          family: Roboto
...          size: 14.0
...          weight: 400
...          baseline: alphabetic
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "bottom"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`PreferredSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) widget doesn't apply size constraints to its children. Therefore the problem was that the column overflowed.

The solution is to constrain the size of the columns children by e.g. wrapping them in a `SizedBox` (also the `AppBar`).

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + 50 + 50),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Text("top"),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: kToolbarHeight + 50,
          child: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
            bottom: const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Text("bottom"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: _buildBody(),
);
```

Solution from this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109150)